# How to set z-index of SlideJs lower than z-index of dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I am using SlideJs plugin from http://www.slidesjs.com/.

I am facing z-index issue.

```
  You can see example code from http://jsfiddle.net/wnTPS/
```

SlideJs-slideshow is below the dropdown menu. When i hover the menu then dropdown menu hides behind the slideshow. I tried to give highest z-index to dropdown menu but issue could not be resloved.

Please tell me best solution to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: The only thing I can say is z-index only works on positioned elements. Otherwise, I can't do anything without seeing your code.

Comment: Okay, I added my code on jsfiddle 
Please check it from this link : http://jsfiddle.net/wnTPS/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wnTPS/3/

I think that should fix the problem. I gave ID slides postion of relative and a z-index of 0, and I gave the menu ID a z-index of 1. Note that z-index will only work with positioned elements. The highest index will appear on top.

```
#menu{
    width:1024px;
    height:50px; 
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid;
    z-index: 1;
}
#menu li{display:inline; height:20px; display:block; float:left; overflow:hidden;   }

#menu li:hover{overflow:visible;}
#menu li ul li{float:none;}
#menu li a{display:inline-block; width:100px}
#slides
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;   
}
```